# Out of memory error. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: out-of-memory, processing, minim

My current project heavy on the code thus far. I would like to add music to it using minim (I'm using a pc) but I keep getting hit with the out of memory error. The song will run but extremely choppy and it makes the program unusable. I changed the max memory in preferences but after trying 4gb with no luck, I figured this just wasn't going to work. Can anyone please look at my code and tell me a way to maybe compress things to save space? or a way to make my program run the way it is?

here is all the code:

```java
import ddf.minim.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.effects.*;
import ddf.minim.signals.*;
import ddf.minim.spi.*;
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;


Minim minim;
AudioPlayer player;

final int stateMenu = 0;
final int RedBox   = 1;
final int BlueBox = 2;
final int GreenBox = 3;
int state = stateMenu;
  float x, y, r, g, b, radius;
int timer; 

//
// font
PFont font;
PFont Amatic;
//

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// main functions

void setup()
{
  // runs only once
  //
  size(800, 700);
  smooth();
  minim = new Minim (this);
  font = createFont("ARCARTER-78.vlw", 14);
  textFont(font);
  //Amatic = createFont("Amatic-Bold.ttf",60);
  //textFont(Amatic);
  frameRate(15);
} // func
//
void draw()
{
  // the main routine. It handels the states.
  // runs again and again
  switch (state) {
  case stateMenu:
    showMenu();
    break;
  case RedBox:
    handleRedBox();
     player = minim.loadFile("SuperLove.mp3");
     player.play();
    break;
  case BlueBox:
    handleBlueBox();
    break;
  case GreenBox:
  handleGreenBox();
  break;
  default:
    println ("Unknown state (in draw) "
      + state
      + " ++++++++++++++++++++++");
    exit();
    break;
  } // switch
  //
} // func
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// keyboard functions

void keyPressed() {
  // keyboard. Also different depending on the state.
  switch (state) {
  case stateMenu:
    keyPressedForStateMenu();
    break;
  case RedBox:
    keyPressedForRedBox();
    break;
  case BlueBox:
    keyPressedForBlueBox();
    break;
  case GreenBox:
    keyPressedForGreenBox();
    break;
  default:
    println ("Unknown state (in keypressed) "
      + state
      + " ++++++++++++++++++++++");
    exit();
    break;
  } // switch
  //
} // func
void keyPressedForStateMenu() {
  //
  switch(key) {
  case '1':
    state = RedBox;
    break;
  case '2':
    state = BlueBox;
        background(255);
    break;
    case '3':
    state = GreenBox;
    break;
  case 'x':
  case 'X':
    // quit
    exit();
    break;
  default:
    // do nothing
    break;
  }// switch
  //
} // func
void keyPressedForRedBox() {
  // any key is possible
  switch(key) {
  default:
    state = stateMenu;
    break;
  } // switch
  //
} // func
void keyPressedForBlueBox() {
  // any key is possible
  switch(key) {
  default:
    state = stateMenu;
    break;
  } // switch
}//
  void keyPressedForGreenBox(){
      switch(key) {
  default:
    state = stateMenu;
    break;
      }
} // func

// ----------------------------------------------------------------
// functions to show the menu and functions that are called from the menu.
// They depend on the states and are called by draw().

void showMenu() {
  background(255);
  fill(0);
  textSize(45);
  //textFont(Amatic);
  text(" Music Box ", 330, 250, 3);
  textFont(font);
  textSize(14);
  text("Press 1 for Red ", 350, 300);
  textSize(14);
  text("Press 2 for Blue ", 350, 325);
  textSize(14);
  text("Press 3 for Green", 350, 350);
  textSize(14);
  // exit button
  text("Press x to quit ", 350, 375);
} 

void handleRedBox() {
  background(255);
  stroke(255,0,0);
  color from = color(100,random(255),2);
  color to = color(0,200,0);
  color interA = lerpColor (to,from,.44);
  int x = 100;
  while (x < width/2 || x> width/2 ) {
    int y = 100;
    while (y <height/2 || y > height/2) {
      blendMode(DIFFERENCE);
      noStroke();
      fill(interA);
      quadstuff(); 
      strokeWeight(5);
      stroke(0,random(255),0);
      line(width/2,height/2,mouseY,mouseX);
      translate(width, height);
      rotate(radians(frameCount));
      y = y + 50;
    }
    x = x + 50;
  }
ghostcirc();
ghostcirc2();
}

void ghostcirc(){
  int w = 0;
  while (w < width) {
    int q = 0;
    while (q <height) {
      blendMode(ADD);
      fill(random(61), random(90), random(250));
      ellipse(255,255,100,100);; 
      noStroke();
      translate(width, height);
      rotate(radians(frameCount));
      q = q + 100;
    }
    w = w + 50;
  }
}

void ghostcirc2(){
  for (int w= 0; w < width; w+=10) {    
      blendMode(ADD);
      fill(random(61), random(90), random(250));
      ellipse(50,50,75,75);; 
      noStroke();
      translate(width, height);
      rotate(radians(frameCount));
      //if (keyPressed == true){
      //    fill(random(100), random(90), random(250));
      }
    }

void quadstuff() {
    int rad = 60;      // Width of the shape
  float xpos, ypos;    // Starting position of shape    

  float xspeed = 2.8;  // Speed of the shape
  float yspeed = 2.2;  // Speed of the shape

  xpos = width/2;
  ypos = height/2; 
  //ellipse(mouseX+x, mouseY+y, 100,100);
  quad(xpos, ypos, rad, rad, mouseX+rad, mouseY+rad, xspeed, yspeed);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(5);
}

void handleBlueBox() {
  Zon();
} 

void Zon(){
    blendMode(REPLACE);
  frameRate(75);
  noStroke();
  smooth();
  color from = color(2,217,227);
  color to = color(0,127,193);
  color interA = lerpColor (from,to,.24);
   // use frameCount to move x, use modulo to keep it within bounds
  x = frameCount % width;

  // use millis() and a timer to change the y every 2 seconds
  if (millis() - timer >= 8000) {
    y = random(height);
    timer = millis();
  }

  // use frameCount and noise to change the red color component
  r = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * 60;

  // use frameCount and modulo to change the green color component
  g = frameCount % 1;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the blue color component
  b = 255 - noise(1 + frameCount * 0.025) * 255;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the radius
  radius = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * mouseX;

  color c = color(r, g, b);
  fill(c);
  ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);
}

void Vert(){
  frameRate(45);
   // use frameCount to move x, use modulo to keep it within bounds
  x = frameCount % width;

  // use millis() and a timer to change the y every 2 seconds
  if (millis() - timer >= 8000) {
    y = random(height);
    timer = millis();
  }

  // use frameCount and noise to change the red color component
  r = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * 255;

  // use frameCount and modulo to change the green color component
  g = frameCount % 1;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the blue color component
  b = 255 - noise(1 + frameCount * 0.025) * 255;

  // use frameCount and noise to change the radius
  radius = noise(frameCount * 0.01) * mouseX;

  color c = color(r, g, b);
  fill(c);
  ellipse(y, x, radius, radius);
}

void handleGreenBox() {
    background(255);
  fill(0);
  textSize(32);
  text(" Some stuff", 150, 100, 3);
  textSize(14);
  text("..... some text ", 100, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only load your sound files once!

The `draw()` function is called 60 times per second, and inside of that you have this code:

```java
case RedBox:
    handleRedBox();
     player = minim.loadFile("SuperLove.mp3");
```

In this case, that sound file is going to be called 60 times per second. That's not what you want to do.

Instead, load all of your sound files from the `setup()` function, and then refer to them inside the `draw()` function.